# Ref value "bleeding" over into all v-for instances of component

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

Nuxt3 project, using script setup in all components.

I have a card component which handles it's own database delete and pending state of delete. Below is the delete button, with pendingDelete state to show a spinner while deleting:

```
// in template of NoteCard
<button
@click.prevent="showConfirmModal = true"
v-if="!pendingDelete"
>
DELETE
</button>
<span v-else class="loading loading-spinner"></span>
```

I use a composable for the db operation, which is called from the child component itself and gives the pending state:

```
// in script setup of NoteCard
const { dbDelete, pending: pendingDelete, error } = useDbDelete;

const deleteNote = async () => {
  await dbDelete("notes", props.note.id);
  if (!error.value) {
    emit("deleted");
  }
};
```

The composable is defined as:

```
//useDbDelete.js

const pending = ref(false);
const error = ref(null);
const result = ref(null);

const dbDelete = async (endpoint, id) => {
  pending.value = true;
  //delete from db
  try {
    await $fetch(`/api/${endpoint}/${id}/delete`, {
      method: "DELETE",
    });
    result.value = "Success";
  } catch (err) {
    error.value = err.message;
  }
  pending.value = false;
};

export default { dbDelete, result, pending, error };
```

In the parent, I render this card for each instance:

```
// in template of parent
<NoteCard
v-for="note in item?.notes"
:key="note.id"
/>
```

When I delete, all instances of card shows the spinner. Why is this? Shouldn't each card be able to handle it's own pendingDelete state? I know that if I were handling this pending state in the parent, I'd need to have unique values and maintain an array for this state, but since each instance of the component handles it internally, shouldn't it be okay?

I've tried to move the v-for to a div wrapping the component. No avail.

Tried using index instead of ID as :key, same issue.

Comment: Can you show how your pendingDelete is defined in your NoteCard component? And how you toggle it from false to true?

Comment: "Shouldn't each card be able to handle it's own pendingDelete state?" Yes, but you've not shown enough code to demonstrate the problem.  Please review how to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question so that others can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @yoduh
Thanks for your comment, I have updated to include the code for pendingDelete.

Comment: @Ellrohir thank you, I've added the code of the composable itself along with the pendingDelete part.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. Now the problem seems pretty straigtforward and I posted a solution that should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having your composable written like that, `const pending = ref(false);` is shared across the whole application. You need to wrap it inside a function and export this function to be isolated from the rest. And you `return` the parts you want to use in your components instead of exporting them directly.

Like this:

```
export function useDbDelete() {
  const pending = ref(false);
  const error = ref(null);
  const result = ref(null);

  const dbDelete = async (endpoint, id) => {
    pending.value = true;
    //delete from db
    try {
      // await $fetch(`/api/${endpoint}/${id}/delete`, {
      //  method: 'DELETE',
      // });
      result.value = 'Success';
    } catch (err) {
      error.value = err.message;
    }
    setTimeout(() => (pending.value = false), 3000);
  };

  return { dbDelete, result, pending, error };
}
```

Then you only need to change the definition in `NoteCard` (add the brackets to make it a function):

```
const { dbDelete, pending: pendingDelete, error } = useDbDelete();
```

Quick demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-cvre6j?file=app.vue

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to provide an answer! That worked like a charm.

Comment: Happy to hear it helped :)